# Pentaho Report Designer: Passing list of values as parameters to report

Tags: sql, list, parameters, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Report Objective: Performance analysis of players by statistics comparison

[Desired Report Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clgp5.jpg)

Please refer to the layout and read on. The player names need to be added from a list which could be anything like entry text box, multicheck box, dropdown etc. If I select Jake Tyler in this list, the report should refresh and show me the statistics from him. Then when I select Adam Smith, he should show up as the next entry below Jake with his respective stats.

I know how to pass individual players as parameters in the query using Pentaho parameters and tagging them in the condition using SQL as:

```
 'where  PlayerName = ${playername}'
```

But I need to know how to pass multiple player names in a similar fashion to generate this report using multivalue String parameters.

Can you please please guide me on how to do this? I have heard things like x-actions which could work but I don't know how to use that. I am sure this will help a lot of people who are trying to achieve something similar which might seem complex to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `where  PlayerName IN (${playername})`.
The list should be correctly passed from the parameter to query.
and the parameter also should get data correctly. 

 **Eg**:

```
    select 'Jake Taylor' as pn
    union
    select 'Adam Smith' as pn
    union 
    select 'Chris Lawson' as pn
```

or

```
    select distinct column_name from table_name
```

this can be sent to parameter (in `Add parameter` window) and your main query can be prepared as I explained above using `IN`

**NB**: You can use only `Display types` like: `Multi value list`, `Multi selection box` etc. Not drop downs which pass only single value.

Comment: I have a situation where the firstname and lastname of the player are in different columns. If now I want to pass these two fields together as the list in parameters, how do you suggest I do this?  

For parameter:  
`select distinct concat(fname, ' ', lname) AS player_name
from player_table`  

Main Query:  
`select fname, lname
from player_table
where concat(fname, ' ',lname) IN (${player_name})`  

Output is 1 row of 1 player. I get desired result if I input names directly as:  

`IN('Adam Smith', 'Chris Lawson','Jake Taylor')`  

But not with the parameter, Cld u suggest a fix plz?